# Webserver with Apache2 Maria DB, error The requested URL was not found

Tags: raspberry-pi, phpmyadmin, mariadb, apache2, raspberry-pi3

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 and I want to create a webserver with it. I downloaded Apache 2 and Maria DB. Now I can open the localhost and  see the Apache2 Debian default page but when I type http://localhost/phpmadmin I get an error. It says:
Not found
The requested URL was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.54(Raspbian) Server at localhost Port 80

Does anyone know how to fix this or knows a tutorial where it is explained because I coudn´t find a solution.

Comment: Do you have a `phpmadmin` directory in the `/var/www` directory? Have you also confirmed the spelling of the URL? The location in your question is missing the `y` in phpm**y**admin ... 